# PowerApps MySl - Dropdown Issues

Tags: mysql, powerapps

I am experiencing some issues with using a dropdown on my app.
I have created the DataCard and included a dropdown within it, I have then set my items info to point to my MySql Platform and the required information.
When I open it in Preview the App through the Powerapps website I am able to see my dropdown working correctly but when I try opening this on my mobile phone these boxes no long work, they dont provide any information in the dropdown.
Is there any specific setting I could be missing?

Comment: First of all you should check if you have access to the db from the application in your mobile phone. Can you please create a textbox and write any information from the database? For example a field from a row or something?

Comment: @BrankVictoria it turns out there is a setting in the overall app that needs to be turned off, this is a known issue so I have now managed to get the information to appear. thank you for your help anyway

Comment: @Paula, can you share that setting please?

Comment: @BrankVictoria its the Enable App Embedding User Experience once it is turned off the app will behave normally

Comment: Thanks for share the info @Paula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable App Embedding User Experience once it is turned off the app will behave normally